# Scaling a grading system

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I wasnt quite sure what to call this question. But here is my issue (it might be super simple)

I have the following grading system:

**Some pseudocode**

```
If the score of a user is < 40% then failed

if the score of a user is >= 40 <75 then the user gets a bronze medal

if the score of a user is >=75 <90 then the user gets a silver medal

if the score of a user is >90 then the user gets a gold medal
```

Now this is fairly simple however the problem occours when i dynamicly change the starting percentage (in the above case the starting percentage is `40%`)

Say for instance i change the starting percentage to `80%` then the same rules has to be applied but the gaps between has to be moved accordingly so a user still can get all three types of medals.

My question is how can i do this?

Comment: You can do this any way you want. Is a linear interpolation okay for you? (If the threshold goes to $70\%$, the higher medals would start at $87.5\%$ and $95\%$ resp.)

Comment: @AlexR Yes linear is fine. as long as all three medals can be gained

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to interpolate linearly, you must solve
$$75\% = a \cdot 40\% + (1-a) \cdot 100\%\\
90\% = b \cdot 40\% + (1-b) \cdot 100\%$$
This particular choice yields $a = \frac5{12}$ and $b = \frac16$.
Then given a new threshold $t$, the percentages for silver and gold would be
$$p_s = a \cdot t + (1-a) \cdot 100\% \\
p_g = b \cdot t + (1-b) \cdot 100\%$$

Comment: So just to be completely clear if the new threshold is 70% then i would do 70 * 40 + (1 - 70) * 100 ?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen No. You need to find $a$ and $b$ first. Then plug in $t=70\%$ in the bottom equations with $a$ and $b$ as above.